# Notify When app is open from iOS device

Tags: ios, notifications, detection

My app is running in background and user open another app like user open apple Map or google map then its notify in my app that "User open apple/google Map" or any other please give me any suggestion if its possible.

Comment: With the `URL Scheme`, you could let `other apps` pass the additional parameter to identify themselves and receive it from `launchOptions` of `AppDelegate`.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible (and most users would consider this behaviour a pretty horrible invasion of their privacy anyway).

Comment: You might be able to do it with cracked android, but not ios.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you cannot get a notification when someone opens another app. You can probably simulate it though. You should be able to get a notification when your app is no longer active, and a notification when the screen is locked. If you get a notification that your app is no longer active and the screen is not locked, then that means the user user went back to the home screen or opened another app.

Comment: Yes, its done but our requirement is like this so. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer data between applications within the same application group. For instance, you can simulate notifications from one of your apps to another. Yet, you cannot listen for changes in app state for application out of your application group, and that is considered expected behaviour. If you are trying to listen for changes in application that you have not developed - this is not possible.